# I'm trying to create a website with python, in an odd way

Tags: javascript, python, html

Here's my code:

```
with open('index.html', 'w') as html:
    title = input('Title of the page? ').capitalize()
    h2 = input('Heading for your website: ').capitalize()
    p1 = input('First paragraph: ').capitalize()
    p2 = input('Second paragraph: ').capitalize()
    a = '''
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <title> {} </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
        <h2> {} </h2>
        </center>
        <div id='well'>
            <p style='position: relative; left: 100px'> {} </p>
            <p style='position: relative; left: 100px'> {} </p>
            <input type='button' value='test' onClick='Button()'>
            <p id='lol'> </p>
        </div>
        <script>
        function Button()
            \{
            document.getElementById('lol').innerHTML = 'hello';

            \}

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
'''.format(title, h2, p1, p2)
    html.write(a)
```

Everything worked perfectly fine until I attempted to add the javascript function with the `{ }` brackets, and the program thought they were part of the format function, how do I get past this? I've tried putting \ infront of it, but it didn't work, (btw, any ideas I should add to this very simple concept? :) )

Comment: You can use normal string substitution `'foo %s baz' % ('bar')`

Comment: I did it, it worked fine, is there another way where I can still use the `.format()` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to double curly braces. Instead of escaping with \, you should have {{ and }}.

Comment: You are a champion. Thank you!

Comment: @Samir. you should mark this answer if it's the one you ended up using.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround (and a good practice) is NOT mix JavaScript code into HTML. Instead, you leave hooks in HTML for JavaScript.

See http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html